# How to send JavaScript object via form submit in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I want to pass a JavaScript object via form submit in JSP. When the form is submitted the action redirect to another JSP, but the objects of the previous window can't be found after redirecting. If I want to send an object to the redirecting window, How it can be possible? the object contains some methods, So `JSON.stringify` is not working. Is it even possible?

Comment: Give code, not story

Comment: You can only send textual data, which means you can only send objects that are serializable. Functions are not serializable, that's why `JSON.stringify()` ignores them.

Comment: Is it impossible to send the objects that are not serializable ?